# Remove some button text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a button with an icon and my question is if there is a way in HTML/JS/JQuery or CSS to search in the document for the specific button and **remove/hide just the text** of the button and not the icon?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = -1 }, new { @class = "btn-edit" }) |
```

Comment: @MilindAnantwar-done please check

Comment: What language is this. It doesn't look like plain JavaScript.

Comment: @source.rar-this is asp .net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rendered anchor tag has class `.glyphicon.glyphicon-pencil`. You can use `.text('')` or `.html('')` to set empty text:

```
$('a.glyphicon.glyphicon-pencil').text('');
```

Comment: Thanks Milind,but in the view source this button have the following value <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" href="/gro/Edit/2">Edit</a> |maybe I can use some search for the class?

Answer (score 2):

Are you just looking for a simple DOM method?

```
document.getElementById("my_button").value = "";
```

or the JQuery equivalent

```
$("#my-button").val('');
```

or as seen above by Milind Anantwar use the class

```
$('.btn-edit').val(''); // I think this still works though "text" and "HTML" may as well
```

Comment: hanks Milind,but in the view source this button have the following value <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" href="/gro/Edit/2">Edit</a> |maybe I can use some search for the class?

Comment: the confusion/difficulty is that you mentioned a button, when you meant a hyperlink.  If the class is consistent then you could use the last option. Are you looking to remove the link from the page? make it not visible? show the text, but disable the hyperlink?